# How to show Social share buttons outside the post?

Tags: the-content

i am getting social share button inside of every post but i need ouside of every post

For reference please find the attached image.

i need like this
[image]

Comment: Where are these coming from? Your theme? A plug-in? Code you’ve added yourself? If they’re not something you developed you will need to ask the author.

Comment: From plugin it is coming

Answer (score 0):

i am using astrid theme so we have to put this code

below 49 line in class="entry-summary"

wp-content\themes\astrid\template-parts\content.php